# Ubuntu Freeze if kept untouched for a few minutes

Tags: freeze, ubuntu-14.04

So I have Ubuntu 14.04 Installed on my system with a few "tweaks", mainly ccsm. I also have google chromium browser installed as well. I do a lot of work in the browser and usually have 10+ tabs open in my system.

I also like to use the multi-window (Workspace) and have 8 Workspaces (thus one of the reasons for ccsm).

Once I leave the computer and try to come back (before the screen locks), the computer is COMPLETELY frozen with my HDD running at very high speeds. I have a system monitor that monitors the CPU activity and HD activity and right before those things freezes, my RAM is at 100% and so is my HDD.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me FIGURE OUT what the problem is? I've been using ubuntu since '08 so I'm familiar with it. I just don't know where to start!

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I can not deal with the problem until I install the following packages as follows

**sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal**

You could get the detailed reason from http://www.howtoeverything.net/linux/hardware/random-freezes-integrated-hd-4000-graphics

Maybe you have to consider the Google Chrome or Chromium, whose two or more different Flash plugins conflict with each other, and the freeze problem disappear after you Disable the Flash plugins in the webpage opened by inputting

**chrome://plugins**

in the URL address of Chrome

Or another useful method of changing the chrome plugins is to [uninstall the google-chrome completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium),and then [install the current chrome](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-linux-12-xx-13-xx/) with newest flash plugin.

After all the above are done, the system need restart.

Hope it can help. Good luck!